# Got a NullReferenceException error asp.net core mvc and can't resolve it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a website where I display datas from a SIEMENS module.

I followed that tutorial : https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/112623/Read-Parse-JSON-data-from-URL-and-display-in-HTML-Table-in-ASPNet-MVC/

But that error appears : `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Machine_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml @foreach (var item in ModelI`

So I created 3 files on ASP.NET Core MVC (that a developer advised me to use this framework).
Here is my JsonObject.cs, that I created automatically with my json file :

```
using System.Text.Json;


namespace Auth.Models
{
    public class JsonObject
    {
        public int mode_auto { get; set; }
        public int mode_arret_urgence { get; set; }
        public int mode_secours { get; set; }
        public int BP_avancer_bobine { get; set; }
        public int BP_avancer_debut { get; set; }
        public int BP_avancer { get; set; }
        public int BP_reculer { get; set; }
        public int Guillotine { get; set; }
        public int Gouttiere_detecte { get; set; }
        public int taille_debitee { get; set; }
        public int long_demande { get; set; }
        public int long_sortie { get; set; }
        public int nbs_angles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then, here is my Controller (called SiemensController.cs) :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Auth.Controllers
{
    public class SiemensController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Auth.Models.JsonObject> jsonObjects = new List<Auth.Models.JsonObject>();
            string baseurl = "http://31.43.187.129/awp/Profileuse/test.json";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
                HttpResponseMessage Res = client.GetAsync(baseurl).Result;
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    jsonObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Auth.Models.JsonObject>>(response);
                }
                return View(jsonObjects);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And there is my HTML file :

```
@Model Auth.Models.JsonObject

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>mode_auto</th>
    <th>mode_arret_urgence</th>
</tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><%: item.mode_auto %></td>
            <td><%: item.arret_urgence %></td>
        </tr>
    }
        
</table>
```

I don't really understand how Controllers work, with Views etc.
If you can help me and explain to me how does it work?

Comment: take some courses or see some videos on plural sight rather then directly jumping over

Comment: Seems like you never defined Model (which you are trying to iterate over) - that's also why you get a NullRefereceException

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Please set a breakpoint at `jsonObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Auth.Models.JsonObject>>(response);` to see the result of the jsonObjects.

Comment: Here is the result of what happened when I made the breackpoint at jsonObjetcs = [...] : on `@foreach (var item in Model)` , I got a message that tell me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the value of jsonObjects, you can refer the below code to show it:

```
@model IEnumerable<Auth.Models.JsonObject>//change here...

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>mode_auto</th>
        <th>mode_arret_urgence</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.mode_auto </td>
            <td>@item.mode_arret_urgence</td>//keep the same with model class
          
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

result:

[image]

Read [Get started with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) to know more.

Comment: I changed the first line `@model IEnumerable<Auth.Models.JsonObject>` and the `@item.mode_arret_urgence` line, but I still have the problem. I'll see if I can understand more with the ASP.NET Documentation.

Comment: @MarieLefort You can set breakpoint at the index action to see where it get null. Because, when you pass data from controller to view as`return View(jsonObjects);`, you need to make sure  the data that you want to pass is not null. So I suggest you to see the value of jsonObjects.